# How can I change my screen name?

Tags: pc, watch-dogs

My screen name in Watch_Dogs is incredibly unimaginative and doesn't match my screen name anywhere else in any of my other games. It also includes my real name, which I don't really want.

How can I change it?

For what it's worth, I don't even know where it came from. I *think* it's my uPlay username, which I set years and years ago with the first Assassins Creed that used it.

Comment: Are you playing this on PC?

Comment: @agent86 Yep I am

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your screen name in uPlay enabled games is indeed your uPlay username, Watch_Dogs included.

Unfortunately, on PC, it's not currently possible to change your uPlay username.  There have been [a lot of complaints](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/782218-Why-can-t-I-change-my-username/page25?s=ab4d4bf328f758f3a9c3579f28f241fc) [about this](https://www.change.org/en-AU/petitions/ubisoft-uplay-let-us-change-usernames) but the only thing Ubisoft is willing to say is "We're thinking about letting you do this at some point in the future, but have no timeframe for when you will be able to."

For example, this was yesterday:

> The Uplay development team are actively working on a system that will address both these issues however, once the name change system is live you will be able to use a name of your choice instead of MIGHTY206774.

A week ago:

> Once we have ironed out all the issues with the name change system, we will make it available for all our users. Until that time we thank you for your patience.

Or from 2013:

> Unfortunately Uplay account usernames cannot be modified at this time. They are looking at implementing this feature in the future, but there isn't currently a time-frame on it.

On Xbox Live at least, your uPlay account is tied to your Gamertag, so changing your Gamertag will make you show up in-game as that name.  However, when you access any of the uPlay menus, it will show your uPlay username instead.

Comment: Damnit! If I had known this when I made a uPlay account all those years ago... This is the first Ubisoft game I've ever played online. Yet another reason to hate uPlay.

Comment: @MarkHenderson, yeah.  I wish I'd picked a bit more strategically myself.  My Gamertag and uPlay name don't line up, and that bugs me to no end :/